# How can I handle using multiple variables depending on which element of an iterator I am using? Aka, how can I DRY up this ruby code?

Tags: ruby, iterator

I have some variables that look like this:

```
 top_script_path = "path/to/top"
 bottom_script_path = "path/to/bottom"
 script_names = ["top", "bottom"]
```

and I'd like to call each of the scripts

```
 `#{top_script_path} "top"`
 puts "top script successful"
 `#{bottom_script_path} "bottom"`
 puts "bottom script successful"
```

This solution, however, doesn't feel DRY enough to me. I'd like to be able to do something like

```
 script_names.each do |name|
     `#{#{name}_script_path} #{name}`
     puts "#{name} script successful"
 end
```

Obviously, it isn't possible to put a #{expression} inside of a #{expression} as above, but is there any other way to dry up this code with a loop?

Comment: Why do your variables look like that? If you're calling them in a loop then put them in an array. Without knowing specifics it's hard to help more, but so far it looks like you have a prefix and a script name, and you're just doing it wrong.

Comment: It's completely possible that's what's happening. Could you provide an example of the variable structure you're suggesting? Are you suggesting just passing another variable into the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hashes:

```rb
script_paths = {
  :top => 'path/to/top',
  :bottom => 'path/to/bottom',
}

script_names = script_paths.keys

script_names.each do |name|
  # `...`
  puts "#{script_paths[name]} #{name}"
end
```

Run:

```
$ ruby qq.rb 
path/to/top top
path/to/bottom bottom
```

Comment: I ultimately went with this answer although the "eval()" response below was also very interesting and effective

Comment: `eval` here is breaking a butterfly on the wheel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the idiom, but I did feel that the hash version was a little bit cleaner.

Comment: `eval` is very powerful, but is slower and more dangerous. If you can avoid using it, do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
script_names.each do |name|
  `#{eval("#{name}_script_path")} #{name}`
  puts "#{name} script successful"
end
```

Comment: That may be better. You may want to answer that.

Comment: Its Okay.. :-) You edit if you want. :-) Your approach is correct. No need to create a Hash for that.. I think, that others did. `Array` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the variables into one structure, something like:

```
scripts = {
  'top' => 'path/to/top',
  'bottom' => 'path/to/bottom'
}

scripts.each do |name, path|
  `#{path} #{name}`
  puts "#{name} script successful"
end
```

If you are writing some kind of build script, consider using [Rake](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake).